# How to configure Lync message persistence format?

Tags: lync, lync-2013

I'm on a project using Lync 2013. Our integration connector reads messages from the Lync server's SQL DB. Currently, 1 to 1 messages are being stored as RTF but conference messages are stored as HTML. I have been told that the message storage format is configurable, but I can't find anywhere in the Lync Server Control Panel to change it. For my project, I would prefer that all messages be RTF, as I have found that the HTML format loses the 'high importance' flag.

Does anyone know how to set the message storage format?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That sounds like a Client Policy setting.

Have a look at the DisableHTMLIM property on the client policy you're using, and see if that helps?